# How to calculate distance traveled or velocity from accelerometer and gyroscope?

Tags: quaternions, python

Currently, I am working on a project where I need to calculate the certain Gait Parameters.

Experiment Setup: I have two sensors placed on the shank(near the ankle) of each leg. Each sensor consists of the timestamp, accelerometer, gyroscope and quaternion data with an internal frequency of 100Hz which stores the whole walk data as a comma-separated .txt file.

Now here I want to calculate the stride length, the distance between 2 consecutive heel strike(I can find the timestamp of each heel strike using the gyro data).

Extra parameters: I have subject's height. sensor placement height.

Can anyone push me in the right direction to calculate the distance traveled by the sensor or average velocity?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Your question appears to be [off-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Also, you will have more chances to get an answer on another site if you will show what you have done so far.

Comment: What part of the problem are you having trouble with?

Comment: Distance calculation part. The straight distance between any 2 given points.